# Is there anyway to fade between background images in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, dom, background-image

So I have an interesting image setup and I was wondering if it's possible to fade between two background images. I would assume if there was one, it'd be with multiple background images and opacities... hmm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it'd be with multiple background images and opacities

Yep, that's the way to go. There's no "native" way of tweening background images, I'm afraid.

You may use one of the many Javascript frameworks out there to help you with the animation.

Bad news, sorry :D

Comment: Okay, thanks! Just had to check. Seems like opacity does the trick.